# Output print statement in python does not goes into cron log

Tags: shell-script, cron, logs, raspberry-pi, stdout

my crontab looks like this:

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/LCDinterface/shutdownlauncher.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /home/cronlog
```

Content of `shutdownlauncher.sh` :

```
cd /
cd home/pi/LCDinterface


date
python shutdown.py 
echo ''
cd /
```

Content of `shutdown.py` :

```
if interrupt_happens:
  print ("shutting down")
  time.sleep(3)
  os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
```

If I run `python shutdown.py` or `sh shutdownlauncher.sh` I can always see the output text 'shutting down' in my terminal. But If only cron starts running the bash script, which calls the python script. I never see the text, and it does not appear in the log. The `date` command in sh script appears in my log, but not in the terminal. Can you help me with that? How  to edit the `shutdownlauncher.sh` or the cron job to see the outputs in the terminal, and in the log too? This whole thing runs on a Raspberry Pi 3, I am connected on SSH.

Content of my log file:

```
Fri Apr  7 19:26:33 CEST 2017
Fri Apr  7 19:36:11 CEST 2017
Fri Apr  7 21:18:45 CEST 2017
Sat Apr  8 00:08:09 CEST 2017
Sat Apr  8 00:29:31 CEST 2017
Sat Apr  8 10:08:17 CEST 2017
Sat Apr  8 11:58:35 CEST 2017
```

Comment: Why would you want to run `shutdown` on boot? A `@reboot` cron-job runs when the machine is booting up.

Comment: What "terminal" are you expecting the output to be shown on?

Comment: You should try flushing stdout before  os.system command - sys.stdout.flush()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of print function try use module `syslog`.

```
import syslog
syslog.syslog('System is going to shutdown')
```

Comment: I tried it, It did not help unfortunately. I suspect  python scipt does not actully returns becouse of the shutdown, all my other cronlogs looks nice, and they work the same way:  bash script call python scripts with simple prints

Comment: Give the full path to `python` in your `shutdownlauncher.sh` script.

Comment: why do you want to use python to shutdown system? If you need delay, shutdown provides it

Comment: If I print sys. executable I always get back the same path, so the python version is ok, but i will try it. I use python to shut down, becouse I use GPIO interrupt on raspberry to start the shutdown, it was easy to do in python , works well, only print statement is missing

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

```
python3 -c 'import time; print("foo"); time.sleep(1); print("bar")'
```

With:

```
python3 -c 'import time; print("foo"); time.sleep(1); print("bar")' | cat
```

You'll notice that when `python3`'s output goes to that pipe, `foo` and `bar` are only printed at the end.

Or:

```
$ python3 -c 'import os, signal; print("foo"); os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM); print("bar")'
foo
zsh: terminated  python3 -c
$ python3 -c 'import os, signal; print("foo"); os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM); print("bar")' | cat
zsh: terminated  python3 -c  |
zsh: done        cat
```

Like in most languages, when standard output doesn't go to a terminal device (for user consumption), it is buffered which saves having to make too many unnecessary writes.

And since `shutdown` ends up killing every process including that `python` script, the buffer is never flushed.

You could explicitly request the stdout buffer to be flush before calling `shutdown` (or `kill` in my example):

```
$ python3 -c 'import os, signal, sys; print("foo"); sys.stdout.flush(); os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM); print("bar")' | cat
foo
zsh: terminated  python3 -c  |
zsh: done        cat
```

But here, that message should rather go to stderr than stdout and stderr is not buffered even if doesn't go to a tty device, so:

```
$ python3 -c 'import os, signal, sys; print("foo", file=sys.stderr); os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM); print("bar")' 2>&1 | cat
foo
zsh: terminated  python3 -c  2>&1 |
zsh: done        cat
```